# Laravel get all products from nested categories

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get all products from the nested categories by using eloquent...

DB structure

```
product
id
name

categories
id
parent_id
name

product_categories
product_id
category_id
```

Models

Product Model

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'product_categories');
}
public function scopeGetCategoriesProducts($query,$category){
    return $query->with('categories')
        ->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($category) {
            $q->where('parent_id', $category)
                ->orWhere('categories.id', $category);
        })->where('status',1);
}
```

Category Model

```
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,'product_categories');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category', 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Category', 'parent_id');
}

public function childrenRecursive(){
    return $this->children()->with('childrenRecursive');
}
```

I have three level category tree ... By the code that i have i can get products from two levels...
Can someone help with this ? I'm strongly believe that there is a way to solve this with eloquent. Something like this

```
public function scopeGetCategoriesProducts($query,$category){
    return $query->with('categories')
        ->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($category) {
            $q->with('parent')
            ->whereHas('parent', function ($que) use ($category) {
                $que->where('id',$category);
            })->where('parent_id', $category)
                ->orWhere('categories.id', $category);
        })->where('status',1);
}
```

Thanks for your help... waiting for your suggestions

Comment: I would suggest having a look at nested sets. https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: Is that scope on the Product model or the Category model?